# Getting the form of a childprocess

Tags: c#, .net, forms

i am trying to get the main form of a process that i started, but the FromChildHandle and FromHandle always return null. the MainWindowHandle however is nonzero.

```
IntPtr p = process_wrapper.MainWindowHandle;
Form form = (Form) Control.FromChildHandle(p);
if (form != null)
{
    form.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only retrieve a form as a control, if the form in question has been generated by your application. You cannot retrieve a form from another process, as your parent process is not aware of the handle <->Control mapping of the child process.

If you just want to "stop" the child process (`form.close()` ?) You can simple stop the complete process. Either "Clean", or by force:

`process.CloseMainWindow()` vs `process.kill()`

Comment: thanks. the process is started from my application. so it is a child process. and i want to explicitly call form.close() to test something specific to that.

Comment: @clamp Even if the process is invoked from your PARENT process, it's the child process that is creating the form, and this is part of another application scope. And that's why you cannot access it from the ParentProcess.